# Editing Blender normals

Tags: mesh, export, edit-mode, normals, unity

I'm currently creating a character for the Unity game engine inside of Blender. The characters meshes are seperated into several objects to allow switching of equipment pieces (upperbody, lowebody, feet, hands, ...) inside of Unity lateron. However this is where my problem pops up. The screenshot below displays the intersection between the characters arm and its hand.

[image: hand_objectmode]

Currently I recon that the seam is related the direction of the vertex normals. In this screenshot I've joined the 2 objects to display the different directions the vertex normals are facing.

[image: hand_editmode]

I've been attempting to fix this issue using several different techniques, including edgesplits, adding loops, ... before noticing Blenders **Edit Normals modifier**. But I still wasn't able to get the right result. I fear the modifier doesn't offer the fidelity that is required to fix the direction of the normals on my particular mesh.

Am I using wrong settings or is there any workaround that helps me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.
Just found an easy workaround using the Data Transfer modifier. Below are the steps I took to fix it:

1. Created copies of all my objects (body, head, hands, feet, ...)
2. Joined them together into 1 single object
3. Used the Data Transfer on each of the remaining original objects
4. Settings: Face Corner Data -> Custom Normals and Source object the newly created full character object